# Input.mousePosition.x or y equivalent on Raycast with World Space canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm trying to convert a mouse event into a VR Raycast event.

I've `Input.mousePosition.x` & `Input.mousePosition.y` as the coordinate of a mouse click event. I want to apply the same event on a VR Raycast hit.

I've the following code

```
Ray ray = new Ray(CameraRay.transform.position, CameraRay.transform.forward);
RaycastHit hit;

if (GetComponent<Collider>().Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) {
     Debug.Log ("True");
    Vector3 point = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(hit.point);
} else {
    Debug.Log ("False");
}
```

From the Raycast hit point, how do I get the equivalent x-y coordinates of where the Ray hits the collider?

**Update:**

The following script is attached to a color picker object in my Unity setup for Google Cardboard. On hover on the color picker, I want to get the coordinates of where the Raycast hits the collider (so that I can get the color in that coordinate).

[image]

**Question 1:**
On the FixedUpdate, I've an if statement `if (GetComponent<Collider>().Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))` and it's returning false. What am I missing here?

**Question 2:**
Am I correct to assume that if the hit.point is set, I could get the x,y,z coordinates of the point where the ray hits the collider to be point[0], point[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGuGD.png) and point[2]?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a huge expert on VR in Unity, but you would usually use `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint` for these purposes. To use it on the main camera, use these lines:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(CameraRay.transform.position, CameraRay.transform.forward);
RaycastHit hit;

if (GetComponent<Collider>().Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) {
    Vector3 point = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(hit.point);
}
```

The z value gives you the distance from the camera, in case you were interested in that. The Unity documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html

**EDIT:**

Question 1:

```
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(CameraRay.transform.position, Vector3.forward, out hit)) {
     Debug.Log ("True");
    Vector3 point = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(hit.point);
} else {
    Debug.Log ("False");
}
```

Attempt using this code instead, from what I've read, Physics.Raycast() is almost always better to use than Collider.Raycast().

Question 2:

```
Vector3[] point = new Vector3[3] {hit.point.x, hit.point.y, hit.point.z};
```

This creates an array named point that has the three variables assigned, although the z coordinate can be discarded for use on a 2D color wheel.

Comment: I tried implementing this, the code `if (GetComponent<Collider>().Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))` however returns `false`. Would you have any idea why that's happening? Seems my previous code also had the same issue

Comment: Hold on a sec. Why are you even using Collider.Raycast()? Physics.Raycast() is what you would usually use. Can't really do a detailed research while I'm not at home, but try it.

Comment: Tried `Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)` also but didn't work. It's eating my head! Thanks for helping me out though.

Comment: Check your Ray initialization. It may be that what you're trying to hit is too far away. I would Neef

Comment: (hit send too early) need more information to troubleshoot.

Comment: I checked the collider, should be near enough to get hit. Here's my complete code snippet https://codeshare.io/nWWyn and here's the same question with some additional information on http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1243088/how-to-get-raycast-hit-coordinates-on-cardboard.html [awaiting moderation]

Comment: I am getting an Access Denied Exception on the Page. Are you sure you weren't in Edit Mode

Comment: It says the page is `awaiting moderation`; maybe that's why. Anyway I've updated the question above with some more information.

Comment: @ptamzz If this answer has answerred your question, please mark it as correct so the question will appear as having been answered.